# MySQL: store only 1 correct answer (indexing)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have 2 tables: `questions` and `answers`, each question has 4 alternatives and only 1 alternative is correct.

Is there any way to force `answers` table to accept only 1 correct alternative for each question, (something like unique index)?

`answers` table design sample:

```
id    question_id    is_correct    text
0         1            true        blue1
1         1            false       blue2
2         1            false       blue3
3         1            false       blue4
4         2            true        blue5
5         2            false       blue6
6         2            false       blue7
7         2            false       blue8
8         3            true        blue9
9         3            false       blue10
```

Is there away to tell DB to store only 1 correct answer for question_id = 1 ... etc ?

thanks,

Comment: In MySQL, this is difficult to do without a trigger.

Comment: before Trigger to validate if correct answer already exist? (for the question)

Comment: Have null instead of false, and unique(question_id, is_correct).

Comment: I think `null` will not help me to store 3 wrong alternatives

Comment: Of course it will not help you to store 3 wrong alternatives, you'll still have to do that work by yourself... But it will make sure you store max one correct answer per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one way you can do this without a trigger is by storing the information in the `Questions` table rather than the `Answers` table.

You can just include a column `CorrectAnswerId` with a foreign key relationship to the `Answers` table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to allow only one correct answer you can alter your design to this direction.

You can remove the column "is_correct" from the "answers" table and add a column "correct_answer_id" to the "questions" table.
So for each question you will have only one correct answer, by definition.

This design has the obvious advantage that easily enforces the requested restriction as it cannot support more than one correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

2 tables:

- 2 columns and `PRIMARY KEY(question_id, correct_answer_id)`.  The PK will prevent having two correct answers.
- Your current table, but without the `is_correct` column.

You can `JOIN` the two tables if you need the `text` for the 'correct answer'.